# Failing to convert SVG file to EPS file with Inkscape

Tags: svg, inkscape

An warning is given, and no output file is written, with the following:

```
$ inkscape --export-area-drawing --export-text-to-path --without-gui --export-eps=`pwd`/text.eps `pwd`/text.svg
** Message: CairoRenderer: empty bounding box.

** (inkscape-bin:21588): WARNING **: Failed to save pdf to: <current dir>/text.eps
```

Inkscape version: 0.92.2 5c3e80d, 2017-08-06

The contents of "text.svg" is given below.

The problem seems to be the text of the `<flowPara>` element near the end, specifically all the `...........`. Interestingly, if I have fewer periods (`.`) the problem doesn't occur (an EPS file *is* generated), or if I have the same number of more, but change to another character (say `x`), that also works.

Can this behaviour be explained?

Contents of "text.svg":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="1700pt"
   height="863pt"
   viewBox="0 0 2185.0001 1078.75"
   id="svg3342"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="text1_footage_height.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs3344" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#00ff00"
     borderopacity="1"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.24748737"
     inkscape:cx="688.58994"
     inkscape:cy="-452.54794"
     inkscape:document-units="pt"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     units="pt"
     inkscape:window-width="2560"
     inkscape:window-height="1377"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata3347">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,26.387778)">
    <flowRoot
       xml:space="preserve"
       id="flowRoot3352"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:120px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:1px;word-spacing:15px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;"
       transform="translate(-162.85714,-214.95921)"><flowRegion
         id="flowRegion3354"><rect
           id="rect3356"
           width="1700"
           height="3975.4438"
           x="162.85715"
           y="190.17857"
           style="letter-spacing:1px" /></flowRegion>

           <flowPara
         style="font-style:normal;
font-variant:normal;
font-weight:black;
font-stretch:normal;
font-family:Sari Offc;
-inkscape-font-specification:'Sari Offc Black';font-size:120px;line-height:125%;text-align:center;letter-spacing:1px;word-spacing:15px;text-anchor:middle;fill:#ffffff"
         id="flowPara3406">................................................................................</flowPara>
           </flowRoot></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Have you reported this problem to Inkscape? https://inkscape.org/contribute/report-bugs/

Comment: No, I thought it may have been a problem with the way I’m using it rather than a bug (based on the fact that there’s a seemingly legitimate warning message and the program exits cleanly). But maybe I should?

Comment: If possible, before reporting, update to the latest Inkscape version, which is 0.92.4 at the current time (or, if you can, use the ppa for the latest stable 0.92.x version).

Comment: An upgrade to 0.92.4 seems to have fixed this problem, thanks.